# Any Javascript API for maps with country-specific display?

Tags: javascript, maps

Is there any Javascript API that does not display the entire world map and later allows to zoom and click to individual countries, but instead just displays the country we are interested and allows region-level clicks? In other words, I am looking for an API similar to JVectorMap but this does not have comprehensive support for all countries and it does not show street-level view when zooming further deep into state/city level. I hope my requirements are clear. If I am interested only in let's say England's map, I want the map to show just England but allow state and city-level clicks with street-level or near street-level views at the lowest level as an optional feature (not too many details at the lowest-level). Google Maps, jHERE etc. seem to show the entire world map and allow to zoom-in, which is not something I want.

thanks,
Paddy

Comment: If you are zoomed out (so that normally Ireland would show), do you want there to be the background colour where Ireland would be?  Or would it be enough to start zoomed in to the UK?

Comment: Hi Kaitlin, what I was looking at was an API that just displays USA if I am interested in USA and does not show any other countries around USA. Does that answer your questions? I do not want to just start zoomed in the interested country but only the country I am interested to be shown without neighbouring countries.

Comment: Right, but what do you want to show where the other countries are?  Do you want oceans blue and everything else but your target country to be grey?  Do you want *everything* grey, even the oceans?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the street maps for one country to be visible, you could download the Open Street Map data into a PostGIS database for that country and that country only, and generate tiles.  There are several tutorials on how to download data and make tiles, e.g. http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/